# Cannot get SharePoint 2010 document library list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, csom

I need to retrieve an XML file from a document library on a SharePoint 2010. But to do this I first need to be able to get the list. I am using the following code but all I get in return is a whole bunch of exceptions:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://link"))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = credentials;

    List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Title");
    clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The exceptions include:

'clientContext.Web.Lists.Count' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException'

A whole bunch of these: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'

So I'm guessing I'm not getting the list and therefore the fields are not being initialized, but why am I not getting the list? I know the link and title i use are the correct ones since I can access the list perfectly with the credentials i supply on my own.

EDIT

Added new code as solution is now updated:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://link"))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
    var web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Lists);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    List sharedDocumentsList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Title");
    clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more info from below sites for SharePoint list/library operations using CSOM.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976%28v=office.14%29.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057074/how-to-download-upload-files-from-to-sharepoint-2013-using-csom

### UPDATE

Try this:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://link"))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
    var web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.Load(web, w => w.Lists);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    List sharedDocumentsList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Title");
    clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: I've already tried most all of those things but they don't matter if I can't get the list through the code that pretty much ALL of them supply as standard, like the clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle.

Comment: Load the web object before retrieving the list

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it still returns 'clientContext.Web.Lists.Count' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CollectionNotInitializedException'.
I added:

Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

Before trying to retrieve the list.

Comment: I tried your suggested code but still no luck. :( I'm starting to think maybe it could be something serverside? No clue what though since I have succesfully used the same sample code to retrieve a normal List, not a Document Library.

Comment: Exactly From which line do you get an exception?

Comment: Try my updated code..

Comment: Your updated code worked partially.. it looks like I am now able to pull out a Count with content of lists. But as soon as I hit the line: clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList); I get a whole bunch of 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'.

Comment: Please provide the all code to understand your problem properly.

Comment: I've updated my first post. I am not sure if you mean that you need all the exceptions?

Comment: I can tell you this much. I get 30 Lists out into a ListCollection and can actually see the list i need but as soon as i go into any list I start seeing those PropertyOrFieldNotInitialized exceptions. It doesn't matter which list i look into so I am almost certain this must be a serverside issue. Perhaps some sort of missing rights or other.

Comment: List object will be accessed smoothly after it is initialized before.

Comment: I ended up using REST to call the list instead. Thank you for all of your help and I will mark this as you were most helpful in trying to find a solution with me. :)